# How to have a newline before bash prompt?

Tags: bash

How can I configure my bash prompt to have a newline before it?

Instead of:

```
Output1
Output2
kshitiz@ksh$
```

It should have:

```
Output1
Output2

kshitiz@ksh$
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
cd $HOME
more >> .bashrc << 'EOT'
PS1='\n$USER:$PWD>' ; export PS1
EOT
```

This will do it permanently for all your future terminal and console sessions.

To refresh your current sessions with this setting :

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 6):

Find where ever the prompt is defined on your system, typically I grep for `PS1` in `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/profile.d/*` or `$HOME/.bash*`.

Then add a `\n` to the beginning of that definition.

So for example on my Fedora 19 system:

```
[ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
```

So I'd change this line to this:

```
[ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1="\n[\u@\h \W]\\$ "
```

Alternatively if you don't know where it's being defined you can still change it as you'd like using this trick. In your `$HOME/.bashrc` file simply add this line to the bottom of the file:

```
export PS1="\n$PS1"
```

#### Example

```
$ export PS1="\n$PS1"

$ ls
ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0101.jpg  ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0103.jpg
ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0102.jpg  ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0104.jpg

$ ls
ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0101.jpg  ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0103.jpg
ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0102.jpg  ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0104.jpg

$
```

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for an approach to insert a new line only when last command output didn't have a new line at the end of its output. See below how I managed to do so:

```bsh
# https://github.com/dylanaraps/pure-bash-bible#get-the-current-cursor-position
new_line_ps1() {
  local _ y x _
  local LIGHT_YELLOW="\001\033[1;93m\002"
  local     RESET="\001\e[0m\002"

  IFS='[;' read -p $'\e[6n' -d R -rs _ y x _
  if [[ "$x" != 1 ]]; then
    printf "\n${LIGHT_YELLOW}^^ no newline at end of output ^^\n${RESET}"
  fi
}

PS1="\$(new_line_ps1)$PS1"
```

Credits to

- https://github.com/dylanaraps/pure-bash-bible#get-the-current-cursor-position
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944692/520567

Comment: this is the true answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="echo"
```

Using

```
PS1="\n$PS1"
```

messes up bash's character count if you are using colored prompt, which may lead to incorrect wrapping of terminal commands.